# How to mathematically introduce a function class of exponential decay?

Tags: exponential-function, definition, mathematical-modeling, curves

I am not a mathematician so I need help with a correct mathematic definition/description of a function /function class that I will be using for modeling through curve fitting. The function describes an exponentially decaying rate, something like:

$e^{-bx^p}+c$,        $\   \ \ \ \  \ $    where a, c, b,p, x >0

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you remove the backticks(``) from around your equation and use $ instead? If you make it a mathjax block you can format your equation like so: `$e^{-bx^p}+c$` and it will be much cleaner for others to interpret. The edit button should be below your question. (note I wrapped my example in backticks which makes it a code block and so the equation won't be evaluated as mathjax)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. It looks like you have the general formula for the functions you'll use to curve-fit. Can you clarify what more/else you need?

Comment: Hello Mark. I would like a correct introduction of the formula, with the domains and so on f: x--> y ..